# Array, Arraylist or list of lists?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I was going to use a standard array, I need it to x number of rows and be 2 columns

```
double[,] members = new double[x, 2];
```

and loop through all the results I get back and then add them to the array, but as the number of results can change I don't want to pre-define the size of the array...

```
members[0, 0] = cost;
members[x, 1] = tax;
x++;
```

I was looking at resizing the array but would it be easier just using an arraylist or list of lists for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the number of items in the second dimension is fixed, or at least, is predictable, so if you're using Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0, you can use a list of tuples:

```
List<Tuple<double, double>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

// In your loop...
list.Add(Tuple.Create(cost, tax));

// ... later when retrieving some tuple...
int item0cost = list[0].Item1;
int item0tax = list[0].Item2;
```

You can always implement some kind of value object class which has *Cost* and *Tax* properties, but using tuples you can do it as easy as I shown you in my code sample.

Comment: Great, I believe your use case is simple enough for using tuples instead of value objects.

Answer (score 7):

I would have a list of some type, where that type has a cost and a tax.

If space is a premium, it could be a struct with two doubles (btw, would ***decimal*** be more appropriate? It is almost always is a better choice for money), but if so: make it immutable.

For example:

```
public struct YourType {
    private readonly decimal cost, tax;
    public decimal Cost { get { return cost; } }
    public decimal Tax { get { return tax; } }
    public YourType(decimal cost, decimal tax) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.tax = tax;
    }
}
```

With:

```
List<YourType> list = new List<YourType>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: There are known to be exactly 2 columns; going "jagged" is a very expensive way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<T>`.

From [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Query=arraylist):

> ArrayList has been replaced by `List<T>` which is faster, and has more  features.

`T` could be a `List<double>` or a `double[2]` or a `struct` or a 2-tuple... but as stated by Marc, using a `List<List<double>>` is over-doing things if the nested `List` is destined to always have two items.

Comment: There are known to be exactly 2 columns; going "jagged" is a very expensive way to do this

Comment: @Marc A 2-tuple is just as expensive as a jagged array. And of course there is the possibility to create a jagged array the other way round, which would be relatively cheap. But still I'd go with a struct like you suggest. Even if it's just to get meaningful property names.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I didn't mention a tuple; if you mean "because it is a reference type", then sure, that is true of `Tuple<,>`, but that isn't the only kind of tuple. Actually, an array is **marginally** more expensive due to storing the length. Oddly enough, thinking about it, you could just use a `double[]` and double the length, so item "3" is actually composed of arr[6] and arr[7].